# How to get Pivot Table in Query with PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, pivot

I have a question about how to generate a query with Pivot Table(Cross Tab) and I am new to SQL and I would appreciate any help from you.

I have 3 tables in PHPMyAdmin
Structure of the tables:

1.sales Table

[Sales Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5gne.png)

2.eod Table

[eod table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRjxp.png)

3.li_hi Table

[li_hi table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWVp6.png)

in these 3 tables, common is rm_code and expected result is

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBd5t.png)

waiting for some help, thank you very much in advance

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images of links to images.

Comment: You're looking for `join`.

Comment: @AliIshaq yes but type of amount should come in columns

Comment: Your query is not clear. Do you mean you want columns to have different names? You can rename the returned columns. Please post your sample data as formatted text, and more clarity on what operation you're trying to do rather than just a sample of the expected result.

Comment: Thank you for your response.i I have added the expected result image. I am trying to get the sum of the amount by rm_code and type_of_eod as headings

Comment: try to put the table data as textual data